# Scroll And Pause A Data List In Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datalist, marquee

I am working on a website and using a DataList on the homepage that displays Employee Photo and Name.

I am using a marquee tag, but I want to use javascript that scrolls image and name of employee in the 'up' direction. I'd like it to pause for 3-4 secs and then scroll to the next image. I am using this code:

```
<marquee onMouseOver="this.scrollAmount=0" onMouseOut="this.scrollAmount=2" scrollamount="2" Interval="5"  loop="true"  direction="up">
                            <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                                RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="1">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                            <tr><td valign="top"><asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("picpath") %>' Height="100" Width="100" /></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="teachernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("teachername") %>' Font-Size="Smaller" /><br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("designation") %>' Font-Size="Smaller" />
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr align="center"><td valign="bottom"></td></tr>

                            </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList></marquee>
```

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery Marquee Demo](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)

Comment: i want to pause and play marquee automatically after 5-6 seconds